# Calling convention for dynamically created function in (Visual) C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, x86

I use the following types to create a new function at runtime:

```
typedef int (*pfunc)(int);

union funcptr {
  pfunc x;
  byte* y;
};
```

This enables me to write instructions in `y` and afterwards call the function like this:

```
byte* p = (byte*)VirtualAllocEx(GetCurrentProcess(), 0, 1<<16, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE );

// Write some instructions to p

funcptr func;
func.y = p;

int ret = func.x(arg1); // Call the generated function
```

It is crucial to know how C++ prepare arguments (call convention) and therefore I have looked up the project properties (Visual C++) and I can see it uses `__cdecl`. It should put arguments on the stack according to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa271989(v=vs.60).aspx and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl but when I look at the assembly generated, the argument is moved to the EAX register.

I want to be absolutely certain how the arguments is prepared. So have I overlooked something about `cdecl` or is Visual C++ optimizing the call, and if so, how do I ensure it doesn't happen?

Best regards, Lasse Espeholt

Comment: I'm curious what problem you are solving with this technique.

Comment: I'm not into MSVC, but can't you embed the calling convention inside the function pointer type?

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. You must not access a union out of order.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'd worry more about running a function using some dynamically filled binary code than the union trick. The former is much more "undefined". ;)

Comment: @KennyTM: Yes, quite :-)

Comment: @JohnZwinck and others. I'm developing a mini JIT-compiler, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @KerrekSB: accessing a union out of order is *not* undefined behaviour -  C99 explicitly allows type-punning through unions; it can, however, easily lead to undefined behaviour, eg by creating a trap representation, by violating aliasing rules in case of pointer conversions (which should be avoided anyway because pointer types may have different representations) or if the union members have different sizes as only the bytes of the member last used in a store have specified value (in particular, storing values in a smaller member can also invalidate trailing bytes of a larger member)

Comment: @Christoph: OK, question is ambiguously tagged. I was only talking about C++ and Visual-C++. Good point. (MSVS does *not* support C99, by the way, by explicit decree.)

Comment: @KerrekSB Can I do anything so I rely on defined behaviour and still able to do what I want? I'm using Visual C++ but a generic C++ would be nice.

Comment: @lasseespeholt: Yes, sure: Declare the function pointer: `pfunc f;`, then get a char-pointer to its memory: `char * pf = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&f);`, then fill *that* with the correct value. (Casting pointers to char pointers is expressly *not* type punning.) That doesn't mean that the function call itself will make sense; only that your construction up to there is condoned.

Comment: @KerrekSB: in C90, accessing union members out of order is implementation-defined, so it might work even on legacy compilers like VS (SCNR - I know that MS made a strategic decision to focus development on C++ and CLR); it seems that type-punning through unions is indeed illegal in C++, but I actually did not find anything which explicitly forbids it (*at most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time.* - but what about *reading*?) and I'd appreciate it if anyone had a better quote for me...

Comment: @Christoph: Same section (9.5): "At most one member can be active at any time." If you write to one member, that's the active one; reading an inactive member is UB, since "each member is allocated as if it were the sole member of a struct".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `EAX` register is [used for the return value of the function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58.aspx). You state in the comments that you are compiling using [`/Gd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46t77ak2.aspx) and so the function will use [`__cdecl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks.aspx). All the same it would make sense in my view to mark the declaration of your function type `pfunc` with an explicit `__cdecl` so that there can be no scope for confusion and mis-match.

Of course, there's nothing to stop you using one of the other calling conventions supported by your compiler. The most important point is that whatever calling convention you settle on, you should explicitly specify the calling convention for the function pointer since the compiler is only responsible for one half of the interface.

Comment: Accordingly to the project properties I'm using `__cdecl (/Gd)`?

Comment: @lasseespeholt, try `__cdecl` anyway (e.g. `typedef int (__cdecl *pfunc)(int);`) and let us know what happened.

Comment: Sorry, I was mixed up. `EAX` is used for return value of function. Answer updated and is now correct (I believe!!)

Comment: @avakar It worked. But again, project properties says it is `cdecl`. I'll try create a new project. Thanks everyone :)

Comment: @lasseespeholt Please see my updated answer. My original version confused you. Sorry. All calling conventions use EAX register for return values.

Comment: Yup, thanks. I may also have misinterpretated the assembly. And by coincidence it also had the argument in EAX.

Answer (score 2):

At least on Linux, you probably want to use [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/) (foreign function interface), and it has even been ported to other systems (including Windows).

And if you want to do machine code generation at runtime, consider using [GNU lightning](http://www.gnu.org/s/lightning/), DotGnu's [libjit](http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/), [LLVM](http://llvm.org/). LuaJit's [dynasm](http://luajit.org/dynasm.html) etc You could also generate C code into `foo.c`, get it compiled by forking a `gcc -fPIC -shared foo.c -o foo.so` command, and `dlopen("./foo.so", RTLD_GLOBAL)` (and Windows have equivalent ability)

Comment: GNU lightning looks promising. But for this pet-project I want to do it all myself - including x86 assembly. But I guess I could look at the source code to see how they generate and call a function.

Comment: libjit is currently maintained by [Aleksey Demakov](http://demakov.com/projects/); you can get the most recent version from [git.savannah.gnu.org](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/dotgnu-pnet/libjit.git); an alternative to libffi is [dyncall](http://dyncall.org/), which supports MSVC, whereas the Windows version of libffi needs to be built with MinGW or Cygwin